# Android: video thumbnails

Tags: android, video, thumbnails

I have a video player for playing movies. I am looking forward towards scrolling the video and getting the tiny thumbnails. Just like you get when a play a video at dailymotion.com where you slide through a video and the respective thumbnails (tiny) can be seen to give you an idea about the location in the movie where the slider is pointing at. Is it possible to achieve the same functionality in android?

Looking forward to your suggestions. 
Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this but in android 2.2 and earlier version

```
ImageView view = new ImageView(mContext);

            Bitmap bm = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("path video file", MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            view.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Its shows video image and then you can click on it and paly video

Answer (score 0):

Mostly ..If you are targeting application for Tablets then It will help full to user..

for display in video link with blinking(display something running ) as you wrote.very difficult to code.
If I am your side and want this apps I follow this step.

1)I used gridView and images (Gif) for display theview.
   Reason for GIF should look showing running images.

2)After that all become simple onclick on image ,I  call the video as this part you already done. If not then it will better to go for this with direct URL to image.

Note: you can display images with use of parsing or inbuilt it depends upon you.

let me know if you find different solution...